# URL for calling REST service from Android app

Tags: android, rest, spring-boot, tomcat

I made a demo SpringBoot project. It has a REST service and an embeded TomCat server. The project is called demo, it is in RestProject folder, the service is up and running. When I try to call it from mi Android app the URL path is wrong. In the example I have followed it is mentioned that the URL for invoking a service should be `http://localhost/<appln-folder-name>/login/user`

I do not understand what is appln-folder-name? The URL I am using when executing the call is the one below. It consists of the workspace name folder and the name of the project folder.

```
 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://localhost:8080/RestProject/demo/login/user",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this library..
 - Volley (https://developer.android.com/training/volley/)
 - Retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit)
It can help you to access your webservice